# Hats Contest (say good bye to the Winter Bash)

Tags: discussion, contest

## The contest is over and the winner is [10Replies](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2284/2217)

See below for the full results.

---

In case you did not know we have [contests](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest) here on the meta from time to time.

Before the hats are all packed up for another year, lets do something fun to make them last just a bit longer.

The objective of this contest to is model and render a hat (or more then one), but not just any hat, a hat from the [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/). All the hats are laid out **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/278094)**. Keep your hat as close as possible to the original.

**Some rules**:

- Use Blender. (duh)
- Keep it nice, nothing a reasonable, average person wouldn't want to show to a five year old.
- Include .blend file, we want to learn from each other, and yeah we want to check that you really did make it in blender.
- You can edit/change your submission at anytime up until the deadline (1/11/2017 UTC 00:00:00z).
- Late entries are not counted, but you may as well post it (not like there's a prize)
- Only one entry per person
- Downvotes will not be considered when picking the winner

**Winner:**
This is a [popularity contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) where the entry with the most up votes by the vote cut off deadline ([January 14, 2017 at UTC 00:00:00z](https://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/generic?iso=20170115T00&p0=1440&msg=Hat%20contest%20%28voting%29&font=cursive&csz=1)) wins.
The winner will get bragging rights, and not much else. Except for the knowledge you gathered from trying something new.

### Deadlines:

All images must be posted (as an answer below) by **[January 11, 2017 at UTC 00:00:00z](https://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/generic?iso=20170111T00&p0=%3A&msg=Hat%20contest%20%28entries%29&font=cursive&csz=1)**.
Only votes before **[January 14, 2017 at UTC 00:00:00z](https://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/generic?iso=20170115T00&p0=1440&msg=Hat%20contest%20%28voting%29&font=cursive&csz=1)** will count towards the winner.

At or around January 14, 2017 at UTC 00:00:00z this post will get updated with the winners.

---

The winner is [10Replies](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2284/2217) with his "First Responder" hat. congratulations!

Here is the standing and the vote totals at the time the contest ended.

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------+  
| User       | Hat                     | Votes |  
+------------+-------------------------+-------+  
| 10 Replies | First Responder         | 12    |  
+------------+-------------------------+-------+  
| David      | Maverick                | 10    |  
+------------+-------------------------+-------+  
| Ward       | I Have A Little Dreidel | 8     |  
+------------+-------------------------+-------+  
| Kidus      | Just Here for the Hat   | 6     |  
+------------+-------------------------+-------+  
| *Carlo     | Philantropist           | 6     |  
+------------+-------------------------+-------+  
| Luka ash   | Amped Up                | 5     |  
+------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

*Note* that Carlo submitted his entry after the deadline, and so he is not eligible for the prize.

Here are the links to each post:
[10Replies](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2284/2217), [David](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2285/2217), [Ward](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2281/2217), [Kidus](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2282/2217), [Carlo](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2286/2217), [Luka ash](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2283/2217)

Comment: Nooo! I will never say goodbye to hats!

Comment: @X-27 It's okay, just let go.

Comment: My head will be so cold without hats  ;(

Comment: I'm going to keep the hats by screenshoting my profile pic w/ the hat and setting that as my profile pic. Problem Solved! :)

Comment: @veryrandomme did that last year. it was... unique

Comment: @Ward Do it every year and watch as your endless hat collection grows

Comment: Well played linking to PPCG, whether intentional or not ;)

Comment: so Carlo was "not eligible for the prize" - aww. that is an awfully big loss...

Answer (score 12):

What year is it? Does *your* hat tell you? I didn't think so. High quality hats. Produced by a modern noise free high quality factory.

Now you can know what year it is

## **IN STYLE**

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Upvote for Suzanne

Comment: Just so you know, the last image is a close up of the feather. It is only partially rendered because I didn't quite finish it in time...

Answer (score 10):

### Maverick

[image: the Maverick hat from the 2106 Winter Bash]

<sub>will add blend after I clean up the unused bits, and pack textures</sub>

Answer (score 9):

## HAVE A LITTLE DREIDLE

With under a day to work on this since I leave tomorrow, I’ve decided to take

> Keep your hat as close as possible to the original.

very literally. :D Iḿ not sure how i managed to do poorly at such a simple model, but when you have the kind of lack of experience that I do, itś easy!

[image: Dreidle]

That being said this is probably the laziest and suckiest entry to this contest, but whatevs. hope you enjoy. 
I also [uploaded to sketchfab](https://skfb.ly/YHTD) if you want to see the model in 3D but don't want to 
[image]

Either way, enjoy! have a happy new year.
(I tried making a video of me modelling it, but only was able to capture about half of the process because I'm stupid. I will add that to this thread as soon as I edit it.)

Comment: Nice! You sure are not the "suckiest entry to this contest", especially as yours is the only on so far.

Answer (score 9):

### Philantropist

A little bit late for the competition, but I'll post it anyway:

[image]

[image]

---

The original reference:

[image]

Comment: Very realistic! Great job!

Answer (score 7):

## Just Here for the Hat

I rendered it using blender internal. Modeling was the easiest part. I spent most of my time on the lighting. After lots of trial and errors and after using about a billion lamps I got it to look like the [hat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zSTZ.png). Anyway, here it is.

[image]

And the .blend:

[image]

Comment: That turned out REALLY close to the original. Well done!

Answer (score 5):

## Amped Up

Haven't worked on many other projects other than just one model for the past few weeks so this was a nice little thing to do(and leave until the last minute to complete) I've never done this sort of art style before either.

[image: Amped Up]

Rendered in cycles. Couldn't get the handle bar to look the same, as it had some weird lighting in the original, and also the original was slightly more warped.

[image]